Outer horn inclusions are not inner anodyne
In Kerodon, it is stated that outer horn inclusions are not inner anodyne. This should be true, but a proof is not offered there. It's obvious that the inclusion $\Lambda_0^2, \Lambda_2^2\hookrightarrow \Delta^2$ are not inner anodyne, but I don't know how to prove the same for higher dimensions (for $\Lambda_0^3$, I have some vague ideas, but it's messy).
[Inner anodyne morphisms = smallest class of morphisms closed under retracts, pushouts and transfinite composition that contains all inner horn inclusions.]
Apart from the generators (of the weakly saturated class), I don't really know what inner anodyne morphisms look like, so trying to show that outer horn inclusions aren't built out of inner horn inclusions seems like a dead end. The alternative is to find some inner fibration that doesn't have right lifting property with respect to outer horn inclusions.
The first place to look at is the nerves of categories, but these don't work because as far as nerves are concerned, pretty much everything is contained in the $2$-skeleton of simplices as associativity is guaranteed. So, if I have an outer horn map $\Lambda_0^n\to N(C)$ with $n\geq 4$, I have all $2$-simplices in the horn, hence all the edges (morphisms in $C$) compose well and I can fill the horn (the same applies to inner fibrations between nerves). I've come across this answer which says that a morphism between nerves is Kan iff the categories are fibred and cofibred over groupoids. But that condition only removes the obstacle of filling outer $2, 3$ horns, if I'm not mistaken (and there is no "obstacle" in higher dimensions).
At this stage, my guess is that to obtain such an inner fibration that doesn't have right lifting with respect to outer horn inclusions is to look at something like the "nerve" of an $n$-category where there are fewer associativity constraints than required so that an outer horn exists but cannot be filled.
I'd like to know if there's an example of an inner fibration that fails to be a Kan fibration because right lifting with respect to some outer $n$ horn inclusion fails for $n\geq 3$.  I would also be happy with an answer that somehow shows that outer horn inclusions cannot be built out of inner horn inclusions.

I can construct an $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ such that the inner fibration $\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\Delta^0$ does not have the RLP wrt any outer horn inclusion in dimension $n\ge2$. Would that answer the question?

Yes, it would @Thorgott

Let $X$ be a Kan complex and $X^{\triangleleft}=\Delta^0\ast X$ the $\infty$-category obtained by adjoining an initial object $\emptyset\in X^{\triangleleft}$ (the cone point). Taking a map $\partial\Delta^{n-1}\rightarrow X$ that does not extend along $\partial\Delta^{n-1}\hookrightarrow\Delta^{n-1}$ and applying $\Delta^0\ast(-)$ yields a map $\Lambda_0^n\rightarrow X^{\triangleleft}$ that does not extend along $\Lambda_0^n\hookrightarrow\Delta^n$. Thus, if $X$ represents a homotopy type with non-trivial $(n-2)$-th homotopy group, then the inner fibration $X^{\triangleleft}\rightarrow\Delta^0$ does not have the RLP w.r.t. $\Lambda_0^n\rightarrow\Delta^n$. You can take e.g. $X=\prod_{i\ge0}S^i$ to achieve this for all $n\ge2$. Note that $X^{\triangleleft}\rightarrow\Delta^0$ is an isofibration/categorical fibration, so this shows these outer horn inclusions are not even Joyal equivalences.

That's neat! Thanks

Out of curiosity, is there a reason to take the product of spheres rather than the coproduct?

@NaïmFavier None particular, it was just the first thing to come to mind. I suppose it feels more natural cause in connected settings, it makes sure you stay connected. (As an aside, you can also take $X=\prod_{i\ge1}S^1$, which is connected, but $X^{\triangleleft}$ still doesn't have the RLP w.r.t. the outer $2$-horns cause it isn't a Kan complex.)
